# MUI Autocomplete: How to update the redux store , when clear input options?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, state

I'm trying to do when the user clear the input I have to update the react-redux store. Thanks

<Autocomplete
multiple
id="tags-outlined"
options={filters}
onInputChange={(event, newInputValue, reason) => {
dispatch(appActions.setFilter({ label: newInputValue }));
}}
// inputValue={filters}
// onClick={(e) => {
//   handleClick();
// }}
onClose={(event, reason) => {
alert(event, reason);
}}
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
defaultValue={filters}
filterSelectedOptions
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Filter By" placeholder="Filter Options " />}
sx={{
'& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
p: 1
},
'& .MuiAutocomplete-tag': {
bgcolor: 'primary.lighter',
border: '1px solid',
borderColor: 'primary.light',
'& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
color: 'primary.main',
'&:hover': {
color: 'primary.dark'
}
}
}
}}
/>

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to do two things. Check is the input empty as well as check is `backspace` key is pressed. Inside that condition dispatch a redux action that should clear the store.